# Increment row on each button click

Tags: excel, vba

I want, with each click, to update cell value to next cell value in another sheet then print the value.

```
Sub SerPrint()

i = 1

'when button click it change to `c3 c4 c5 and C......
' until the end of table
Sheet1.Range("n7").Value = Sheet2.Range("C"2 + i )
'like Value in cell N7 from sheet1 have value from c2 Sheet2 then
' after i click it change to c3,c4,c5,c....

Sheet1.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
' then print out

End Sub
```

Comment: give range address information- which cell you want to change with value of which other cell (name sheets in this information)

Comment: like Value in cell N7 from sheet1 have value from c2 Sheet2 then after i click it change to c3,c4,c5,c....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add public variable to control offset of rows each time you execute your sub.

Add this line at the top of any Module in your project

```
Public iOffset as Long
```

And your sub will looks like this:

```
Sub SerPrint()

'let's start with value of C2 from Sheet2
Sheet1.Range("n7").Value = Sheet2.Range("C2").Offset(iOffset, 0)

Sheet1.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
' then print out

'here we increment our public variable for next click to make C3, C4...
iOffset = iOffset + 1


End Sub
```

Comment: There is no control of end of the table in the code above as there are too little information to figure it out.

Comment: iOffset is variable which increment each time you call sub before it's public one. `Offset` is a range modification property which allows to move to cell based on (row, column) parameters... yes, it's a bit like for loop...

Answer (score 1):

In your style ..

```
Sheet1.Range("n7").Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & format(2 + i) )
```

If you want to use Offset ..

```
Sheet1.Range("n7").Value = Sheet2.Range("C2").Offset(i,0)
```